# Display a message when trigger fires in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have a table where stock quantity is recorded. I set trigger to warn the user when stock goes low. When testing it, the trigger fires, displays the message, but the stock is not updated. What do I do wrong? Is there another way to set the trigger (not using SIGNAL SQLSTATE)? I use phpMyAdmin 4.2.7.1 in uWamp. Thank you for suggestions.

Code for the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER low_stock_message  
AFTER update ON stock_quantity 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.Regular_Menu < 50) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning, Regular Menu has a low stock!';
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.Savers < 50) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning, Savers Menu has a low stock';
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.Breakfast < 50) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning,  Breakfast Menu has a low stock!';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test query:

```
UPDATE stock_quantity
SET Regular_Menu=48
WHERE Outlet_ID=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're using `SIGNAL SQL STATE '02000'` which, [according to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html#signal-effects), is an exception signal. In particular, "If the signal is unhandled in a function, statements end."

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `sqlstate '45000'` and set `message_text` for that. Let me explain it using an example .. In the example follow, our goal is to prevent users from voting for their own posts, something like this:

**Stub**

```
create table votes (user_id int);

delimiter //

create trigger prevent_self_votes before insert on votes
for each row
begin
    if (new.user_id = 12) then   // 12 is id of voter
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'You cannot vote for yourself, dude!';
    end if;
end //

delimiter ;
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
$sql = 'insert into votes values (:user_id)';
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
if ($statement === false) {
    echo 'statement is false';
    exit();
}

try {
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':user_id'=>12));
    if ($result === false) {
        $error = $statement->errorInfo();
        print_r($error);
        echo "$error[2] ... is the error reported by trigger\n";
    }
    else {
        print_r($result);
        echo 'Inserted', "\n";
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**Result**

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => 45000
    [1] => 1644
    [2] => You cannot vote for yourself, dude!
)
You cannot vote for yourself, dude! ... is the error reported by trigger
```

As you notice here, you could use the output of `$statement->errorInfo()[2]` to extract information provided by the trigger.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php says that the first item in the array is SQLSTATE ANSI SQL error code, second item is driver specific error code and third item is driver specific error message.